# Reset form not clicking on any button - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, reset

I want to reset a `form` if it is possible on `onInit()`.

I know that I can reset a `form` using onSubmit, or simply taking the `#myForm=NgForm` (I am already using these options). I want something else. I want to select my `form` from my Typescript file. **I do not want `onSubmit` or from HTML**

I have tried several ways, but I always get the same error (the property changes depending on the command):

> [ts] Property 'form' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. [2339]

I have tried:

```
var x = <HTMLFormElement> document.getElementById("mySelect").form.id;

var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").form.id;

 document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

$("#client.frm")[0].reset();

$("#client")[0].reset();
```

but nothing works.

Comment: Use `@ViewChild("myForm") form;` to get a reference to the form

Comment: How does it work? I have never used it

Comment: Add that line within your TS file, and it will populate with your form. You can then do `this.form.reset()` from inside your component. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Works. Thank you :)